# Arduino Sketch Name Available in Sketch Code

Tags: arduino

**Arduino Sketch Name Available in Sketch Code**

Is there a variable or such within the std Arduino scope, say setup method, with the actual sketch file name?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  Could you expand?  the filename is, well, the name of the file you opened (the sketch itself) - do you need to know this at run time? is that what you are after?

Answer (score 2):

The `__FILE__` macro provides the sketch filename.

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial){}
  Serial.println(__FILE__);
}

void loop() {}
```